# Error in displaying listview due to syntax error at runtime

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How to solve SQLiteLog(3507): (1) near "=": syntax error sqlite in android. My database works fine with error activities. The logcat shows the syntax error in the line 1.

```
public void openAndQueryDatabase()
 {
    try
 {          
db = openOrCreateDatabase( "mydatabase.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null ); 

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ table + "where name='"+ name + "'",  null);  //line 1

        int count = cursor.getColumnCount();


        if (cursor != null )
        {
            if  (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do 
                {
                     for (int i =0 ; i< count; i++)
                    {
                    String data = cursor.getString(i);
                    details.add(data);
                    }
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
            } 
         }      

    }   
    catch (SQLiteException se )
    {   

        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error in the code");
    } 

    finally 
    {

            db.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space between your table name and the `where` keyword:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ table + " where name='"+ name + "'",  null);
```

Also consider using `?` bind args for literals, e.g.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ table + " where name=?", new String[] { name });
```

Comment: Spacing worked. But still listview cannot be displayed due to error : 04-18 11:49:43.686: E/Trace(882): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: That's just noise in logcat and not a real error you should be concerned of.